# Looking for a small comparators which do compare a input

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

and output when reach the set value。　
Or can anyone tell a simple circuit to build one.

Comment: How small is small? SOT-23? SC-70?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are comparators available in small packages.

The first vendor I checked has them in packages as small as 0.85 x 0.85 mm XSON package.

[image]

Comment: I once bought LDOs in that same package. They're like flakes of pepper, and you need a microscope to get them oriented correctly!